# SQL Case Statement - If first 'when' returns null then complete the 2nd when

Tags: sql-server, null, case-statement

Just wondering if anyone can help me , I am running a case statement that references a different table. It needs to look up the make, model and year of a car as well as the position (FL,FR,BL,BR) and return the kit number.

Up to 4 entries can exist in the table for the same vehicle with the fitting position column specifying which kit number to be selected, in order to only return 1 result i believe i need to put this in the where section of the query, if i add it anywhere else more than 1 value is returned.

However 4 entries won't always exist for the vehicle. A kit can exist for FL & BL but not FR and BR. Because of me adding the position column into the where section  'null' is returned.Rather than it returning nothing i want it to return the next part of the case statement.

This is where the sql works because a kit is available for FL

```
SELECT CAST (CASE WHEN '002' != 'UNI'  THEN T0.U_MPLFK ELSE 'NOKIT' END AS VARCHAR)
FROM 
[@CSOL_MILFORD]  T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[@CSOL_VEHICLES]  T1 ON  T0.[U_VehicleRef]  = T1.[U_VehicleRef] 
WHERE
T1.U_Manufacturer = 'Ford' 
AND 
T1.U_Model = 'Galaxy' 
AND
T0.U_MPLFK > 1
AND
T0.U_FittingPosition = 'FL'
```

However when it changes to

```
SELECT CAST (CASE WHEN '002' != 'UNI'  THEN T0.U_MPLFK ELSE 'NOKIT' END AS VARCHAR)
FROM 
[@CSOL_MILFORD]  T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[@CSOL_VEHICLES]  T1 ON  T0.[U_VehicleRef]  = T1.[U_VehicleRef] 
WHERE
T1.U_Manufacturer = 'Ford' 
AND 
T1.U_Model = 'Galaxy' 
AND
T0.U_MPLFK > 1
AND
T0.U_FittingPosition = 'FR'
```

I get no value retuned, i want it to return 'NOKIT'

Many Thanks,

Roisin

Comment: question is not completely clear. Always  `'002' != 'UNI'` condition is satisfied so `T0.U_MPLFK` will be returned from `case`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are saying. '002' is in fact a screen reference that can change to something different. It can be UNI or blank the only time it wants to look at the table for the kit number is when it is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` returns a row with `null` columns if its `on` condition fails.  So you could move the conditions to the `on` part of a `left join`.  Something like:

```
...
FROM    @CSOL_VEHICLES T1
LEFT JOIN
        @CSOL_MILFORD T0
ON      T0.U_VehicleRef  = T1.U_VehicleRef
        AND T0.U_MPLFK > 1
        AND T0.U_FittingPosition = 'FR'
WHERE   T1.U_Manufacturer = 'Ford' 
        AND T1.U_Model = 'Galaxy'
```

Having the condition in the `on` clause instead of the `where` clause means you'll get a row with `nulls` instead of no row.

Comment: Hello, - Many Thanks works just how i wanted :) However it still returns the 2 rows, because 'no kit' is actually going to be replaced with a universal kit number two kit numbers are returned. But i actually only want the first kit number to be returned. Many Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "first kit number"? Can you give an example?

Comment: So for the ford galaxy two entries exist, the FR & BL. When the fitting position is returned for the FR it should return 002. When BL 007. As it stands it will return 007 when  i put the position as BL on one row and NOKIT on the 2nd row. I only want it to return the 007. If i put the kit position as 'BR' 2 results are returned both as 'NOKIT; i only want one.

Comment: I have just made this change: but i'm not sure if it will completely work: SELECT TOP 1 CAST (CASE WHEN '001' != 'UNI' AND T0.U_FittingPosition ='BL'  THEN '9525' + T0.U_MPLFK ELSE 'NOKIT' END AS VARCHAR) AS ITEMCODE 
FROM [@CSOL_VEHICLES] T1
LEFT JOIN  
 [@CSOL_MILFORD] T0
ON  T0.[U_VehicleRef]  = T1.[U_VehicleRef] 
 AND T0.U_MPLFK > 1
 AND T0.U_FittingPosition ='BL'
WHERE
 T1.U_Manufacturer = 'Ford' 
 AND 
 T1.U_Model = 'Galaxy' 
ORDER BY
 ITEMCODE

Comment: This seems to have done the trick perfect thank you very much!